Postman: How to fix "Fatal error in , line 0 # Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804"?
I have a test suite consisting of 75 "get" calls. If I run the tests individually they work, although some take a long time (about 3 or 4 minutes). If I run the entire test suite at once, Postman crashes on the fourth test, which is the one that returns the highest values. If I run the entire test suite from the command line using newman, it fails on the fourth test, returning the error:
Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804 (see crbug.com/1201626)
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 00000069B8BFC810
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 00007FF7EBB171AB node::SetCppgcReference+16075
 2: 00007FF7EBA1649F node::TriggerNodeReport+70223
 3: 00007FF7EC8E2E72 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF7EC37A0D5 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+855861
 5: 00007FF7EC219F46 v8::Message::GetIsolate+16294
 6: 00007FF7EC03B983 v8::CodeEvent::GetFunctionName+181699
 7: 00007FF78C55AAFA

The 75 Get calls all run the same test, but apply it to 75 different services; the test is packaged into a package that is called in each Get script:
function Status_200() {
    pm.test("Status test", function () {
        if (pm.response.code === 200) {
        console.log("Status is OK");
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Expected status 200 but got ${pm.response.code}`);
    }
 });
}

// Call the test function
Status_200();

function NumberRange(start, end, step) {
  if (typeof(step) == 'undefined') {
    step = Math.sign(end - start);
  }

  if (Math.sign(step) != Math.sign(end - start)) {
    console.log(`Can't count from ${start} to ${end} using ${step} as stepsize.`);
  } else {
    var numberList = [];
    if (start > end) {
      while (start > end) {
        numberList.push(start);
        start += step;
      }
    } else {
      while (start < end) {
        numberList.push(start);
        start += step;
      }
    }
    console.log(numberList.join());
    return numberList;
  }
}

NumberRange(10, 5, -2);
NumberRange(1, 2);
NumberRange(2, 1);
NumberRange(1, 3, 2);
NumberRange(1, 3, -2);
NumberRange(3, 1, -2);
NumberRange(3, 1, 2);

// Export the function to be used in other modules
module.exports = {
    Status_200,
    NumberRange
};

